# How to host a Datashader-Bokeh Interactive Map as a web application?

Tags: bokeh, holoviews, datashader

I have recently created an interactive Datashader-Bokeh Interactive Map that looks like [this NYC Taxi Example](http://datashader.org/getting_started/1_Introduction.html) on a Jupyter Notebook. The dynamic aggregation works beautifully when I run the code locally on my mac.

My question is, is the current technology possible to host this as a web application - e.g. a web app without that Jupyter Notebook interface. And if so, how?

I've come across some articles ([this](https://github.com/bokeh/datashader/issues/147) and [this](https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/pull/959)) that suggest HoloViews might be an appropriate "glue" to stitch up Datashader, Bokeh and Bokeh-server - to make a web application. Though I am wondering if there may be any get-started tutorials / good-practice templates on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are extensive tutorials about using HoloViews to set up a web app or dashboard to show off your Datashader plots; see 
http://holoviz.org/tutorial .

Comment: The tutorial is incredibly high quality - just what I needed to get started. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I am having problems getting the very first tutorial to actually run as an app. https://github.com/pyviz/pyviz/issues/133

Comment: The link to the tutorial should be updated, it gives a 404 - up-to-date  resources are probably available at https://pyviz.org/tutorials/index.html